# Flutter doctor problems

Tags: android, flutter, toolchain

I have problems with flutter doctor
And I tried to fix it but I can't
So and place help me in this problems.
I let an image describe it

[image: https://i.imgur.com/3rI82P8.jpg]

Comment: You can follow [the docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install)

Comment: Have you installed Android Studio ?

Comment: No, I have not installed it yet

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.

Comment: Install Android Studio and execute it at least once to trigger Android SDK installation. Also make sure the computer you use is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

`flutter doctor` is a command that you have to use to see how its going the things with Flutter and if you are able to use the framework or instead require any additional installation. The info displayed in your screenshot is telling you that you have to install Android Studio, VSC and accept some Android licenses. To know more about it you can check the [Flutter installation guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install).

I hope it help you!